# What do "どゃでぇ" meaning?

Tags: meaning, kana

Context:http://mangalifewin.takeshobo.co.jp/rensai/yo-jolife/yo-jo-009/21349/
I try search "どゃでぇ" in Google just get almost nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### The どゃ portion

Notice that the や is basically the same font size as the ど.  This is not どゃ, where the small ゃ is meant to indicate a palatalized glide attaching to the consonant of the previous mora, but rather どや.  <s>I'm vaguely familiar with the adverb どやどや used to describe lots of people milling or rushing about; I wonder if it's used here to indicate the focus of the "camera" rushing towards the character.</s>

**Update:** As explained by Chocolate in the comments, this どや is not from どやどや, but rather from the Kansai-ish どや that is equivalent to Kanto どうだ, as used in the expression どや顔【がお】.  Literally "how's-that face", it's a bit like the English expression "how ya like (it / that / me) now", also used to indicate smug self-satisfaction.

#### The でぇ portion

<s>I'm not sure about the でぇ portion.  I suspect this is used to highlight the self-satisfied smug expression on the character's face, but that is only my intuition.</s>

The でぇ portion appears to be the extended version of sentence-final で, the Kansai-ben equivalent to Kantō-ben emphatic sentence-final particle よ.

#### Reference Links

- For どや, see [the 京ことば section of the Weblio entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%82%84#KYKTB).
- For で, see [the second entry in the 大阪 section of the Weblio entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7#OSAKA).

---

Any comments to clarify or correct the above would be most welcome.

Comment: 「どや[顔]{がお}」の「どや」（←「どうだ、すごいだろう」って意味）でしょうねえ・・絵から見て。。

Comment: @Chocolate、ありがとうございます。「どや顔【がお】」とは初耳（書いてあるものだから、「初目」？）です。勉強になりました。投稿を修正します。

Comment: Couldn't でぇ in this context then be the Kansai-equivalent to the emphatic particle よ? (see e.g. ガキの使いやあらへんで！)

Comment: @Boolicious, I'm not that familiar with Kansai-ben, but I suspect you're right.  I'll dig a bit and update later.

Comment: Boolicious, 疑問詞に関西弁の「で」は付かないので、「どや+関西弁『で』」にはならないと思います。（「どう+よ？」「どこ+よ？」「なに+よ？」「誰+よ？」はいいのにねえ。）

Comment: @Chocolate、「どや」＝「どう」＋「だ」ならば、「どやで」＝「どう」＋「だ」＋「よ」、のでは？[大阪弁「やで」の項目](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%81%A7#OSAKA)もご参照に。

Comment: う～ん・・「どう+や+で。」「どこ+や+で。」「なん+や+で。」「誰+や+で。」はアカンなあ・・・　「どうやねん/どやねん」「どこやねん」「なんやねん」「誰やねん」はええねんけど。関西弁で、疑問文は「で」で終わらへんねん。（「どうだよ」「どこだよ」「なんだよ」「誰だよ」はいいのにねえ・・・）

Comment: @Chocolate さん、Weblio の[この項目](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%82%84#KYKTB)によりますと、京都では「どや」が東京の「どうですか」という意味で、このスレッドの前のコメントではこれが「どうだ」という意味だそうです。そして、関西弁では「や」が関東弁の「だ」と相当すると認識しています。ですと、関西の「どやで」は関東の「どうだよ」と相当すると推定しましたが、Chocolate さんがそうではないと書いて、現在自分は混乱しきっています。元の質問の「どやでぇ」はどう解釈すればよいのか、ご説明いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 関西弁の「どや」っていうのが、近年、関東（全国？）でも俗語で「どや顔」って感じで使われるようになって、この漫画の「どやでぇ」の「どや」も、その俗語の「どや顔」の「どや」なんですけど、この「でぇ」は関西弁の「(～や)でぇ」では（文法的に）ありえないんですが、これを描いた漫画家さんがどういう意図で書かれたのかは、わかんないです。